# ClickOnce and SQL Server Compact database

Tags: c#, clickonce, sdf

My C# console application has embedded MS SQL Server Compact database (.sdf file). When a new version of the application is installed, this file must **not** be overwritten.

.sdf → File Properties → Build Action: Which value should be chosen? The options are None, Compile, Content, Embedded Resource, EntityDeploy, ApplicationDefinition, Page, Resource, SplashScreen, DesignData, DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreatableData and XamlAppDef.

Answer (score 0):

The build action should be "None", but more importantly is the "Copy to output directory".  This should be "Copy if newer."

Comment: I think that copying to output directory is something that is decided on build time. What I need is to configure ClickOnce setup.exe to install .sdf only if doesn't exist... Software update must not overwrite it. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Given that "Copy file if it doesn't currently exist" isn't an option, your best bet is to set it to "Always copy" to a temporary location or filename on the device, then get your C# code to test if the .sdf file already exists, and if not, copy the .sdf file into the proper location.  Not pretty, I know.

Comment: Ok! Connection string is `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.sdf`. So, I renamed the project file `MyDb.sbf` to `MyDbEmpty.sdf` and in the beginning of `Progam.Main()` I check if the file `MyDb.sdf` exists in `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` and if *not*, copy `MyDbEmpty.sdf` to `MyDb.sdf`. Accessing `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` in VS debug run throws exception and it must be handled. Mike Gledhill, thanks for helping!